# Incrementing An Array Crystal Report

Tags: arrays, if-statement, crystal-reports, increment

I have a user inputted parameter that can be 1 value up to how ever many values they enter. Right now where [i] is in the formula that is the index of the array of how many they enter. I need to increment the formula so that it iterates over every one of their parameters but no more than what they enetered. I tried hard coding indexes[1] through [20] but if there were fewer than 20 parameters entered I would get an error.

```
    if TONUMBER({?Order #}[i]) = TONUMBER({V_ORD_COMB.ORDERNO})
    then TRUE
    ELSE

    FALSE
```

This works fine for 1 input value but no more

```
    if TONUMBER({?Order #}[1]) = TONUMBER({V_ORD_COMB.ORDERNO})
    then TRUE
    ELSE

    FALSE
```

This works fine for 3 input values but no less or more

```
    if TONUMBER({?Order #}[1]) = TONUMBER({V_ORD_COMB.ORDERNO})
    then TRUE
    ELSE
    if TONUMBER({?Order #}[2]) = TONUMBER({V_ORD_COMB.ORDERNO})
    then TRUE
    ELSE
    if TONUMBER({?Order #}[3]) = TONUMBER({V_ORD_COMB.ORDERNO})
    then TRUE
    ELSE
    FALSE
```

I am trying to get it to work for any number of inputted parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Local Numbervar i;
Local Stringvar result:="not found";

for i:=1 To Ubound({?Order #}) do (
    if {?Order #}[i]={V_ORD_COMB.ORDERNO} then  (
        result:="found";
        exit for
    );
);

result
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to

```
Local Numbervar i;
Local Booleanvar result:=False;

for i:=1 To Ubound({?Order #}) do (
    if {?Order #}[i]={V_ORD_COMB.ORDERNO} then  (
        result:= TRUE;
        exit for
    );
);

result
```

and it works great! I appreciate the help.